# Autofac 4 with .NetCore API controller not loading

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac

I have an instance where my controller is never instantiated when i use `Autofac`.  I figured I have done something wrong with the configuration, but I cannot figure it out.  I have 2 projects within my solution.  1) API 2) Core   All the models, repository, and services live in the Core.  Only the controllers are in the API.

If I navigate to the default or values controller, they work fine. If I remove the constructor from my `MemberController`, it will work, but I get `NULL` references on the service.  If I add the constructor back, the `MemberController` never loads (break point in constructor and get method) are never hit.

The Service requires a data model on instantiation.  In the instance below, the `MemberController` takes a `MemberService<MemberDM>` as an `IService<IDataModel>`.
I believe I have registered everything within my `AutofacModule`, but it doesn't seem to be working, as the constructor is never hit in `MemberController`.

Any thoughts/help would be much appreciated.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // Add service and create Policy with options
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", p =>
        {
            p.AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowCredentials();
        }));    

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DBConnection:ConnectionString");

        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule(connectionString));

        builder.Populate(services);
        ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();

        appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
    }
}
```

AutofacModule

```
public class AutofacModule :Autofac.Module
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public AutofacModule(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {            
        // Register Connection class and expose IConnection 
        // by passing in the Database connection information
        builder.RegisterType<Connection>() // concrete type
            .As<IConnection>() // abstraction
            .WithParameter("connectionString", _connectionString)
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Register Repository class and expose IRepository
        builder.RegisterType<Repository>() // concrete type
            .As<IRepository>() // abstraction
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Register DataModel as IDataModel 
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IServiceAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("DM"))
            //.AsImplementedInterfaces();
            .As<IDataModel>();

        // Register Service Class as IService
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IServiceAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .Except<IService<IDataModel>>()
            //.AsImplementedInterfaces();
            .As<IService<IDataModel>>();
    }
}
```

IServiceAssembly

```
 public interface IServiceAssembly
{
}
```

MemberController

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MemberController : Controller
{

    private readonly IService<MemberDM> _memberService;

    public MemberController(IService<MemberDM> service)
    {
        _memberService = service;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        var result = await _memberService.Get(id);
        return View(result);
    }}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be because of `.Except<IService<IDataModel>>()` call? If your `MemberDM` implements `IDataModel` interface then it wouldn't be registered as far as I see it

Comment: I tried removing that, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are your services generics? `.Name` for generics returns `TypeName\`n`, where `n` is number of generic parameters. i.e. `MyService<MemberDM>` will return `MyService\`1` as Name, not `MyService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming following:

- `IService<T>` and `IDataModel` implements `IServiceAssembly`.
- All interfaces ending with "DM" or "Service" in your Core project have corresponding implementations.

Then it's enough to have a single DI registration statement in your API project.

```
// Register DataModel as IDataModel 
// Register Service Class as IService
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IServiceAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("DM") || t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: Thanx for this.  I like how you combined them.  I think the issue was me trying to use the actual Interface instead of using .AsImplementedInterfaces().